# Is it possible to aggregate $$ROOT in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following Mongo Collection.

```
[
  {
    "query": "a",
    "page": "p1",
    "clicks": 10,
    "date": "x"
  },
  {
    "query": "b",
    "page": "p1",
    "clicks": 5,
    "date": "x"
  },
  {
    "query": "a",
    "page": "p1",
    "clicks": 5,
    "date": "y"
  },
  {
    "query": "c",
    "page": "p2",
    "clicks": 2,
    "date": "y"
  },
  
]
```

Output Should be like this :

```
 [
      {
        "page" : "p1",
        "most_clicks_query" : "a",
        "sum_of_clicks_for_query" : 15

      },
{
        "page" : "p2",
        "most_clicks_query" : "c",
        "sum_of_clicks_for_query" : 2

      },
  
      
    ]
```

**Logic to get this Output** :

I need the query name  that has most clicks for each page with sum of clicks (for that query)

**What I  ask** :

- I am hoping to  get this result in one aggregation query.
- So I am playing with $$ROOT.
- In this path, now I am stuck with grouping the $$ROOT (to get sum of clicks for  queries).
- Can someone guide me a better path to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the aggregation you're looking for:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "page": "$page",
        "query": "$query"
      },
      "sum_of_clicks_for_query": {
        "$sum": "$clicks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": false,
      "page": "$_id.page",
      "most_clicks_query": "$_id.query",
      "sum_of_clicks_for_query": true
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "sum_of_clicks_for_query": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$page",
      group: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$group"
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uzk3CuSwVRM

Comment: for "p1" , there must be only one document. but your query returns 2 documents for "p1". Anyway, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @PrageethPeiris You're obviously grouping by page AND query. The reason it returns 2 document for `p1` is because `p1` has 2 different queries: `a` an `b`. In your desired result, you're showing `p1` with `"most_clicks_query" : "a"`. So where did the `p1` with `"most_clicks_query" : "b"` go?

Comment: I want to eliminate query 'b' . because query 'a' is the only one that has most clicks for 'p1' . example : 'p1' has total clicks 20. query 'a' contribute 15 clicks and query 'b' contribute 5 clicks.

Comment: @PrageethPeiris not a problem. Updated answer along with Playground link.

Comment: Perfect. The original query I wrote simply needed to be modified to find the max value of `sum_of_clicks_for_query` for each `page`.